# Trig simplification rules

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Can some one please explain to me how $(1+\sin x)(\cos x)-(\sin x)(\cos x)$ simplifies to $(\cos x)$.
I'm having a hard time finding the trig rules. I'm ok at calc but horrible at trig!

Comment: try factoring: $((1+\sin x)-\sin x)\cos x = 1\cdot\cos x = \cos x$

Answer (score 3):

No triggery here. Just simple algebra.
$$(1 + \sin(x))\cos(x) - \sin(x)\cos(x) = \cos(x)+\sin(x)\cos(x)-\sin(x)\cos(x) = \cos(x). $$

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$(1+\sin x)\cos x=\cos x + \sin x \times \cos x$$

Does it ring your bell?

Comment: :( Wow, I hate myself

Comment: Sometimes I heta myself also;(

Comment: @MathStruggler No need to hate yourself

Answer (score 1):

$(1+\sin x)\cos x - \sin x\cos x = \cos x + \sin x\cos x - \sin x\cos x = \cos x$.

No trig formula is required.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easy to see this way. Set $a=\sin(x)$ and $b=\cos(x)$.  Then we have,
$$(1+\sin(x))\cos(x)-\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
$$=(1+a)b-ab$$
$$=1\cdot b+a\cdot b-ab$$
$$=b+ab-ab$$
$$=b$$
$$=\cos(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I did it....
$$(1+\sin x)(\cos x)-(\sin )(\cos x)=(\cos x)$$
$\cos x+\sin x\cos x -\sin x\cos x=\cos x$ (here I just multiplied $(1+\sin x)$ by $(\cos x)$ and got the $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ out of brackets)
$\cos x(1+\sin x-\sin x)$ (I took out the HCF $(\cos x)$)
$\cos x(1)$ (I did basic subtraction to get rid of $\sin x$)
$\cos x$ ($1 \times \cos x = \cos x$)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to try to format your answer because it gets a little bit difficult to follow you.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).